# Erro no xcode: "codesign deseja acessar a chave access de suas chaves"

Tags: xcode

Estou tentando rodar um app a partir do xcode 9.2 no meu iPhone 8 plus (iOS 11.2.1), porém o xcode gera o seguinte erro:

codesign deseja acessar a chave "access" de suas chaves. Para permitir isso, digite a senha das chaves "login".

Mas afinal, que senha é essa? Tentei digitar a senha do meu apple ID, do usuário do meu macbook (high sierra, 10.13.2), que é do tipo administrador, nada funcionou!!! Este app roda pelo simulador sem problemas, mas ao fazer num dispositivo real, não dá certo.

- meu apple ID é do tipo desenvolvedor
- no menu do iphone, ajustes -> usuário apple ID -> iCloud -> Chaves, está como inativo (nunca usei)
- no menu do xcode, preferences -> accounts, já tem cadastrado meu apple ID
- no menu do projeto no xcode, na parte "signing", está marcado "automatically manage signing" e o "Team" está selecionado no meu apple ID

[image: errocodesign]

Comment: creio que essa senha é a do seu user da sua maquina/mac

Comment: Consegui depois que eu digitei minha senha de usuário do Mac e cliquei no botão **Permitir Sempre**.